# POST request works on Postman but not Angular2

Tags: javascript, post, angular, http-post

I'm trying to send a `POST` request on Angular2, but I'm getting the following error:

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I already added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and the request works fine if I try to send it using Postman. However, it doesn't work in my Angular2 app:

**MyService**

```
sendRequest(id: string, state: boolean): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = 'http://MY-URL-HERE';

    return this.http.post(url, {id, state}, options)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        return Observable.throw(err);
      });
  }
```

**MyComponent**

```
change(id, event) {
  this.service.sendRequest(id, event)
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
}
```

Comment: Server-side issue most likely, so can you tell something about the service you are trying to post?

Comment: Yeah CORS issue are server sided, and it depends on what you'r using, apache, nginx , node?

Comment: It's to control some sensors remotely. I need to post an `id` and `state` to tell if that `id` should be on or off. I have the following `header` (I don't have direct access to the server now, I'm not the one who manages it): http://pastebin.com/KB33TPNy